# How to No-op if a duplicate key exception occurs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know I can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and then do a no-op operation in MySQL if a duplication exception occurs, but is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName ....
```

see the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that INSERT IGNORE still doesn't insert a record if a duplicate key exception occurs. helpful.

Comment: It *does* make a hole in your auto_increment counter for that table, however, I find that undesirable ...

Comment: @Landon Incorrect (with InnoDB `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` = 1 (default) or 2

Answer (score 2):

While that is true, I've found that doing `INSERT IGNORE` creates holes in your auto increment ids.  Specifically, if you do an `INSERT IGNORE` and it collides with a current row, no data is written (what you want), **BUT** the auto_increment value for that table gets incremented by one.

If you're narcotic like me, holes in auto increment columns kill you.  So I tend to not do that.  I just do something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (column list) VALUES (value list) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE random_column = random_column
```

This successfully does a no-op.  It's purely a matter of style, but I think this method is cleaner.

Comment: -1

1) your answer is based on a requirement that the table does indeed have an additional column. 2) your answer does not solve the auto_increment "holes" you are talking about. the following SQL illustrates that ID #2 was skipped `CREATE TABLE foo (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Bar INT, Qaz INT, UNIQUE KEY(Bar)) ENGINE=INNODB; 
INSERT foo(Bar) VALUES (1); INSERT foo(Bar) VALUES (1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Qaz = Qaz; INSERT foo(Bar) VALUES (2); SELECT * FROM foo;